# Show multiple results from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Iwas wondering if someone could help me?

I have a table called markers, in this table it stores multiple records each with a name etc. I would like to echo each name however the below code only shows one results. How can I show more than one. Can someone please help I am new to PDO.

```
$stmt = $dtb->query('SELECT * FROM markers');

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $markerName = $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting it each and every time , use an array instead.

#### Rewrite like this...

```
$markerName = array(); //<---- Add here
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $markerName[] = $row['name'];
}
echo implode('<br>',$markerName);  //<---- Implode it up for display
```

Comment: @user3531072, Welcome , you could also give a shot on what YourCommonSense [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23055016/1003917).

Comment: I can take a wild guess who -1 you Shankar, but I'll fix that ;-) Right as usual. Plus, giving a good explanation ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thank you mate :D and I saw the downvotes on your answers and levelled it up too :D

Comment: My pleasure Shankar. Thanks, yeah I think there's something "slithering" amongst us.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Are we a burden to SO community or what ? lol. I really don't understand with -ve votes.

Comment: It's because we are "caring human beings" Shankar. Snakes have a different way of life ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Well- said mate ! :)

Comment: Hehehe believe me, I know what I'm talking about ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to hold the result, in your code, the variable `$markerName` is overwrote on each iteration.

```
$stmt = $dtb->query('SELECT * FROM markers');

$markerName = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $markerName[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Rewrite like this

```
$names = $dtb->query('SELECT * FROM markers')->fetchAll();
```

Being new to PDO, you are supposed to try [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) first, where you can find an answer not only to this one but to many other questions.